On the OEIS sequence A346789
I have a question about the sequence A346789. It states the following:

Given any sufficiently large number $k$, the smallest number having
$k$ as the sum of the cubes of its digits is the concatenation of $a(k \mod 729)$ and zero or more $9$'s.

There isn't much information about what $a$ is. However, there is an example that states:

Let $f(j)$ be the sum of the cubes of the digits of $j$, and let
$g(k)$ be the smallest number such that $f(g(k)) = k$. Then, $g(4609)$ is
the concatenation of $a(4609 \mod 729)$ and zero $9$'s: $a(4609 \mod 729) \equiv a(235) = 1888888888$, and $f(1888888888) = 4609$.

The first five numbers of the sequence ($0, 1, 11, 111, 1111$) make sense but the I don't understand why the next number is $2666888$ and not $11111$. Clearly, the latter is smaller. On that note, $11111$ is the sixth element of A165370 ("Smallest number whose sum of cubes of digits is $n$")
From what I can tell, $f(2666888) \equiv 5 \mod 729$. Looking at the values for $k = 5 \dots 8$, it appears that it was derived by the fact that $f(68) \equiv -1 \mod 729$, so that from $f(2) \equiv 8 \mod 729$, we have $f(268) \equiv 7 \mod 729$, $f(26688) \equiv 6 \mod 729$, and so on.

$a(n)$ is the $n$-th term of that sequence: $a(0)=0$, $a(1)=1$ and so on.

$a$ refers to the sequence that is been defined.

Here is somehow more precise definition of $a(n):=$$A346789(n)$:

$a(n)$ is the smallest integer $m$, such that for every sufficiently large integer $k$, the smallest integer whose sum of cubes of digits is $729k+n$ is $m$ followed by zero or more $9$s.

Using $g(n):=$$A165370(n)$ = the smallest number whose sum of cubes of digits is $n$, we can rewrite this also as

$a(n)$ is the smallest integer $m$, such that for every sufficiently large integer $k$, the $g(729k+n)$ is $m$ followed by zero or more $9$s.

Now consider the example $n=5$. We need to look at the values $g(729k+5)$, and choose the smallest one such that all that follow are just adding $9$ to the end. By a computer search, the first couple values of $g(729k+5)$ starting at $k=0$ are:
$$
11111, 111119, 347777, 2666888, 26668889, \dots.
$$
It can be proven that all subsequent values are of form $2666888$ plus some trailing $9$s. So, $2666888$ satisfies the condition of $m$ in the definition, and so does $26668889$, $266688899$ etc. We want the smallest such $m$, hence we have $a(5)=2666888$. Clearly, $11111$ does not satisfy the property: for $k\geq 2$ none of $g(729k+5)$ are of form $111119\dots 9$.
By the way, from the OEIS record we find that $729k+n\geq 4609$ is sufficient. So $k=7$ always works, leading to yet simpler formulation:

$a(n)$ is $g(5103+n)$ without the trailing $9$s.

Note: The OEIS definition as written does not seem to be correct - for one it has the "smallest integer" just once, but as you see above, we are looking for smallest integer such that some other smallest integer satisfy certain property. It could be fixed by refering to $g(n)$ or $A165370(n)$ in the definition, but at least the author used $g(n)$ a lot in the examples.

Following is a Python script generating all terms of the sequence.
import gurobipy as gp

def A165370(n):
    # formulate as an integer linear programming problem
    model = gp.Model("CubeSumProblem")
    vars = [model.addVar(vtype=gp.GRB.INTEGER, name=f'a{i}', lb=0)
            for i in range(1, 10)]
    model.setObjective(gp.quicksum(vars), gp.GRB.MINIMIZE)
    model.Params.OutputFlag = 0
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(v * i**3 for i, v in enumerate(vars, 1)) == n)
    model.optimize()
    assert(model.status == gp.GRB.OPTIMAL)
    s = sum(round(v.X) for v in vars)
    model.addConstr(gp.quicksum(vars) == s)

    for i in range(9):
        model.setObjective(vars[i], gp.GRB.MAXIMIZE)
        model.optimize()
        assert (model.status == gp.GRB.OPTIMAL)
        model.addConstr(vars[i] == round(vars[i].X))

    result = ''.join(str(i+1) * round(v.X) for i, v in enumerate(vars))
    return int(result) if result else 0

def A346789(n):
    g = A165370(5103+n)
    while g % 10 == 9:
        g //= 10
    return g

for n in range(0, 729):
    print(n, A346789(n))


Sufficiently large $k$ is important. For $a(5)$ we have $k=2192=f(2666888)=f(11111999)$ and note that $2666888<11111999$

@DanielMathias Thank you, my problem was the definition of the sequence - I still think the OEIS definition is wrong or at minimum misleading as stated. However your comment made me rethink the whole thing and find the intented meaning of the sequence.

$a(n)$ is not defined as the smallest integer with a certain property. $a(n)$ is defined as the leading digits of the smallest integer with a certain property.

Well, that's equivalent - "leading digits" are the smallest integer in a certain sequence. My point is the OEIS definition does not mention either.

Let $f(n)$ be the sum of the cubes of the figure of $n$ and let $g(n)$ be the smallest number such that $f(g(n)) = n$.
We have $f(5) = 11111$. An easy way to find a $n$ such that $f(n)=729k+r$ is to add $9$'s to $g(r)$. For example, $f(111119)=729+5$, $f(1111199)=2×729+5$ and $f(11111999)=3×729+5$. By chance, $g(729+5)=111119$. However, $g(3×729+5)=2666888$ (which is indeed smaller than $11111999$). This idea of adding $9$ is finally not that bad since for every $k\geq 3$, $g(729k+5)$ is $2666888$ followed by $k-3$ times the digit $9$.
This is more generally true, if $n$ is sufficiently large, $g(n) = a(n \mod 729)$ followed by sufficiently many $9$'s (where $a$ is A346789). By the above observations, $a(5)$ is $2666888$.
